# Tell if screen is original or replacement on iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, screen

I recently bought a iPhone 5 on eBay. Now I'm suspicious if the screen is the original one or a replacement.
Is there a way I can clarify my concernings?

The screen has problems to recognize my touches and sometimes doesn't work at all.

Here are a few pics of the "suspicious-looking" Screen

[image]

[image]

You can see the different colors on the screen **AFTER** I cleaned the whole screen with a special display cleaner.

Can someone explain this ?

Comment: Are you experiencing problems with the screen?

Comment: Yeah. Added that

Comment: I've a 5S, but that glass looks twice as thick as mine. Another clue is that it doesn't finger-mark half as easily as an iPhone 4S or earlier.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what those marks you are showing are, but I am slightly concerned by the colour of the proximity sensor on the left of the ear piece in photo 1...

Have a look at my previous answer to a similar question:
[How to check if the screen replacement part for iPhone 5s is an original one?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/194934/how-to-check-if-the-screen-replacement-part-for-iphone-5s-is-an-original-one/195009#195009)

This might help also.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is pretty late, but I do think that I have an answer about the discoloration. The iPhone that I bought from Craigslist had similar discoloration around the apple logo, the fingerprint sensor, and the front camera/ear piece. The guy that I bought it from had told me he had kept a screen protector and an otter box on this phone since the day he got it. I put the otter box on, and the only exposed places where the places of discoloration. I can assume that the sun and other light sources caused that discoloration. Your iPhone could have had a case enclosing it, or a screen protector. The sun may have only wore on one area of the screen causing that space to discolor. Your screen is rather thick though.